# Mockito - how to mock Optional().get?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a problem with Mockito - I have following code example

```
     @Mock
 private SomeClass someclass

........

when(Optional.of(someclass).get()).thenReturn(something)
```

It doesn't work, as i'm getting MissingMethodinvocationException. When i tried to mock the Optional
`@Mock private Optional<SomeClass> optional;` 
I'm getting an error that Mockito cannot Mock or spy Optional class. How can I mock Optional.get() behavior?

EDIT: test method:

```
@Test 
public void shouldAlwaysCreteModelTest()    
{       
when(objectsService.findExistingModel(importDto.getCode(), importDto.getName())).thenReturn(Optional.of(model));
 
when(modelService.create(ToCreateModel.class)).thenReturn(model);  
        
final ToCreateModel result = createObjects.retrieveOrCreateModel(importDto); 
    
assertNotNull("result should not be null", result); 
assertEquals("Should create ToCreateModel", model, result);
verify(modelService).create(eq(ToCreateModel.class)); 
}
}
```

Comment: It's because other method in completely another class returns Optional<SomeClass>, but in this method I need to use actual object

Comment: I understand, but still - how can I mock behavior of `Optional.of(someclass).get()`

Comment: Why on earth would you want to mock an Optional? It's only a simple data holder. Use a real optional instance: `Optional.of(something)` and you're good. No mocking necessary and it saves a lot of headaches. Besides `Optional.of(someclass).get() == something` breaks the contract of Optional: if you wrap something in an Optional, you must get it back, not something different (someclass != something)

Comment: The issue with test is caused because of Optional - when the method was receiving normal class, there were no issues with the test, but after changing method parameter to Optional, the test fails when calling `verify()` - I'm getting `Wanted but not invoked` and `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock`. When you test program manually, everything works fine

Comment: What are you verifying? That `.get()` was called? How is that going to help your test assert correct behavior of your program? Why don't you `assertEquals("expected", yourOptional.get());` at the end of your test? Can you show more of your code, with the little context you provide, it's difficult to give a useful answer. But my general recommendation is: don't mock data objects, it causes more harm than good. (and I've seen really bad code mocking `List`s, `Map`s, or `CompletableFuture`s, basically reimplementing them)

Comment: This is test code - it fails last verification
`@Test
 public void shouldAlwaysCreteModelTest()
 {

  when(objectsService.findExistingModel(importDto.getCode(), importDto.getName()))
    .thenReturn(
    Optional.of(model));
  when(modelService.create(ToCreateModel.class)).thenReturn(model);

  final ToCreateModel result = createObjects.retrieveOrCreateModel(importDto);

  assertNotNull("result should not be null", result);
  assertEquals("Should create ToCreateModel", model, result);
  verify(modelService).create(eq(ToCreateModel.class));
 }
}`

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the necessary details. Comments are impossible to read and can get deleted. But my guess would be `eq(Optional.of(ToCreateModel.class))` (but I can only guess. You have yet to show the error message)